# Get all product IDs with an empty short description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce we have thousands of products. We have forgotten to add the short description on some products.

How can I quickly get all product with an empty short description without going through each individual product one by one?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **To the community:** Sorry but this question **is NOT unclear** and what is asked **is something very simple and basic.** Nothing complex and unclear. This question and answer can be useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved making a direct and very simple SQL query in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM  wp_posts WHERE post_excerpt = ''
AND post_status LIKE 'publish' AND post_type LIKE 'product'
```

You will get all products that have an empty short description.

Or you can use this custom hooked function that will display a coma separated list of this product IDs only visible for administrator user role:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'get_products_empty_excerpt', 50 );
function get_products_empty_excerpt(){
    if( ! ( current_user_can('edit_products') ) ) return;
    global $wpdb;
    $ids = $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_excerpt = ''
        AND post_status LIKE 'publish' AND post_type LIKE 'product'
    ");
    if( sizeof($ids) > 0 )
        return '<p>'.implode(', ', $ids).'</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I'd like to comment that there's a missing parenthesis in this line:  

    if( ! ( current_user_can('edit_products') ) return;  

should be  

    if( ! ( current_user_can('edit_products') ) ) return;

Comment: @XenonofArcticus Thanks… I have edited this answer :)